# Updating index values column using dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, replace

So I've read a few helpful posts on this, but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have a dictionary and I would like to use it to update the index of a dataframe which is made up of a bunch of different names.

If a name is present in a index of the dataframe and in the dictionary then I replace it with the new name. If its not present, then instead of replacing with nan, I keep the current name.

This is what I've tried so far:

First attempt:

```
df.index = df.index.map(dictt).fillna(df.index)
```

Error:

```
'value' must be scalar, passed: Index
```

Second attempt

```
df.index = df.index.replace(dictt)
```

Error:

```
'Index object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Third attempt

```
x = dictt.keys()
for name in df.index:
    if name in x:
    df.index[name].map(dictt)
```

Error:

```
only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: The first error is because fillna expects a single value? and you are passing an index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave to convert it to a series:

```
df.index = df.index.map(dictt).to_series(index=df.index).fillna(df.index.to_series())
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. Why was it necessary to convert it to a series?